# Django is not displaying image

Tags: python, django

I am trying to build an e-commerce website using python's Django framework as part of a practice project. However, I am not being able to display my product's image on my landing page.

**Django version**: 3.2.4

**models.py:**

```
class Listing(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    price = models.FloatField()
    description = models.TextField()
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to="auctions/images/", default="")
```

**settings.py:**

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

# Managing media
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

**urls.py:**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import include, path
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [
    path("admin/", admin.site.urls),
    path("", include("auctions.urls"))
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

**views.py**

```
def index(request):
    listings = Listing.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'auctions/index.html', {
        "listings": listings
    })
```

**index.html**

```
{% extends "auctions/layout.html" %}
{% load static %}

{% block body %}
    <h2>Active Listings</h2>

    {% for listing in listings %}
    <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
        <img class="card-img-top" src="{% static listing.image %}" alt="Card image cap">
        <div class="card-body">
            <h5 class="card-title">{{ listing.title }}</h5>
            <p class="card-text">{{ listing.description }}</p>
            <p class="card-text">Price - {{ listing.price }}</p>
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Bid</a>
        </div>
    </div>
    {% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

I am only getting the alt attribute for the `img` tag.

Comment: change `src="{% static listing.image %}"` to `src="{% url listing.image.url %}"`

Comment: you can do this: `src="{{ listing.image.url }}"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned by @Pruthvi Barot you need to change the code you are using in your html from

```
src="{% static listing.image %}"
```

to

```
src="{% url listing.image.url %}"
```

That is because you image as a media and allowing them to served via a url as you define here:

```
# Managing media
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

The static file are in this case images that you placed in the directory and do not manage (upload and delete) from the Django Admin Panel.

another solution mentioned by @MojixCoder is to replace the above mention line of code with

```
src="{{ listing.image.url }}"
```

This is the preferred solution and is the one specified in [Djangos official documentation on MEDIA_URL](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/#media-url) (version 3.2)